# Error posting JSONObject using Volley android studio

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I am sending a JSONObject by using Volley but I get :
value <br of type java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONObject

anyone knows where is the problem?!

here is my java code :

```
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("siteName", "example.com");
        jsonObject.put("field", "android");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        textView.setText(response.getString("websiteInfo"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Toast.makeText(JsonActivity.this, error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            Volley.newRequestQueue(JsonActivity.this).add(objectRequest);
        }
    });
```

and here is my php code :

```
    <?php 
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$obj = json_decode($json);

$website = $obj->{'siteName'};

$field = $obj->{'field'};

$output ='';

$output->websiteInfo = $website.$field;

$jsonObject=json_encode($output);

echo $jsonObject;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing params as a JSONObject.. You should override **getParams** method and pass ur params..

For your reference check the blog : [Android Volley Tutorial – Making HTTP GET, POST, PUT](https://www.itsalif.info/content/android-volley-tutorial-http-get-post-put)

Comment: Hi, thank you. I tried it but didn't work. I tried many ways! sending JSONObject, sending string request and I also tried many php codes. searching on the internet for days and trying everything and finally completely confused, still doesn't work  ...

Comment: can u post ur api and params instead of these php code

Comment: I figured out where the problem was and the received value is shown in my app but now the new problem is that file_get_contents returns null ... isn't there any other way to receive data in php?

Answer (score 0):

This is parsing error. Make sure your server is returning something like this

{
"websiteInfo":"this is a website for health"
}

Comment: Hi and thanks, can it be caused because of I am using localhost? or it doesn't matter?

Comment: No it doesn't matter whatever you're using either localhost or live server. In order to check what's your server is returning use postman.